# How to remove a tab bar from view having two tab bars on top of each other?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I want to remove the black tab bar from the A screen. I tried to do the code below to screen but it removes the white one.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    }
```

[image: tab bars]
[image]

Comment: Why did you use nested UITabBarController?

Comment: created a custom class for UITabBarController and hide which one you need

Comment: generally tab bar is used to manage some UIViewController instances, so why did you trying to manage UITabBarController instance with an other UITabBarController instance?
please tell me what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Funny enough in your case the result might be `self.tabBarController?tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` since your tab bar controller has a tab bar controller of which you want to hide the tab bar. But as others suggested you should probably rethink your view controller hierarchy and avoid 2 tab bar controllers in your case or try to present the second tab bar controller when that tab is being pressed.

Comment: @omartarek32 I want to present the A screen and blue one in a tab bar once an item in the first tab is being pressed.

Comment: @BhavikModi I want to present the A screen and blue one in a tab bar once an item in the first tab is being pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion this not a good user experience for iOS users, but any way please try the following approach and it will works fine with you

1- first of all build try to build the following hierarchy in your stroyboard

[image]

note that the gray view Controller is not `UITabBarController` it just a `UIViewController`, but it contain a `UITabBar` object

2- you need to give the red view controller `stroyboard` id "*RedViewController*" and also give the blue view controller "*BlueViewController*"

3- give the nested `UITabBarItem` **tag 0** for the first UITabBarItem which named "Favorite" and give **tag 1** for second UITabBarItem which named "more"

[image]
4- finally add the following class to the `UIViewController` that have the `UITabBar` object, in our example it will be the gray view controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var blueViewController: UIViewController? = {
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BlueViewController")
}()

lazy var redViewController: UIViewController? = {
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RedViewController")
}()

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var nestedTabBar: UITabBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nestedTabBar.delegate = self
    addRedViewController()
    self.nestedTabBar.selectedItem = self.nestedTabBar.items?.first
}

func addBlueViewController() {

    if let redViewController = redViewController {
        redViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        redViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        redViewController.removeFromParent()
    }

    if let blueViewController = blueViewController {
        addChild(blueViewController)
        blueViewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        containerView.addSubview(blueViewController.view)
        blueViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

func addRedViewController() {

    if let blueViewController = blueViewController {
        blueViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        blueViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        blueViewController.removeFromParent()
    }

    if let redViewController = redViewController {
        addChild(redViewController)
        redViewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        containerView.addSubview(redViewController.view)
        redViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }  
  }
}

extension SecondViewController: UITabBarDelegate {

func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    if item.tag == 0 {
        addRedViewController()
    } else {
        addBlueViewController()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to avoid it after getting more into it.

Comment: you are welcome, please leave comment here if you faced any problem in that solution

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarController?.parent?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Doing the magic but you have to be sure that viewDidLoad is called.